# How to query data of changes in a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

I want to write a complex query for me.

My example records:

```
|   id   |   seed   |         run_date    |   value   |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|    1   |   12     | 2019-01-22 09:00:00 |     0     |
|    2   |   14     | 2019-01-22 09:01:00 |     0     |
|    3   |   15     | 2019-01-22 09:02:33 |     1     |
|    4   |   19     | 2019-01-22 09:04:00 |     1     |
|    5   |   22     | 2019-01-22 09:12:00 |     1     |
|    6   |   28     | 2019-01-22 09:16:00 |     0     |
|    7   |   30     | 2019-01-22 09:18:00 |     0     |
|    8   |   36     | 2019-01-22 09:19:00 |     0     |
|    9   |   44     | 2019-01-22 09:20:00 |     1     |
|   10   |   58     | 2019-01-22 09:21:00 |     1     |
|   11   |   80     | 2019-01-22 09:24:12 |     1     |
|   12   |   120    | 2019-01-22 09:25:00 |     1     |
|   13   |   128    | 2019-01-22 09:26:00 |     1     |
|   14   |   136    | 2019-01-22 09:28:00 |     0     |
```

I want the difference between the ones.

Simply:

```
min(run_date)   max(run_date)      difference

id=3             id=5                seed2-seed1 = 22-15 = 7

id=9             id=13               128-44 = 84
```

Where should I start? How should I do? Anybody have any idea?

Mysql version: 5.7.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: 5.7.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)  @Akina

Comment: It's bad, no window functions... you will need 2 subqueries used 3 table copies each for to find 1's ranges... I recommend to use stored procedure with cursor and temporary table - it will be less expensible.

Comment: Maybe I can update mysql version. If I will update how can I do it? @Akina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe I can update mysql version. If I will update how can I do it?

In MySQL 8+ the query will be

```
with 
cte0 as ( select *, 
                 lag(value) over (order by run_date) lg, 
                 lead(value) over (order by run_date) ld
          from test),
cte1 as ( select *, 
                 row_number() over (order by run_date) rn
          from cte0
          where value = 1 
            and (lg = 0 or lg is null)),
cte2 as ( select *, 
                 row_number() over (order by run_date) rn
          from cte0
          where value = 1 
            and (ld = 0 or ld is null))
select cte1.id `min(run_date)`, 
       cte2.id `max(run_date)`, 
       cte2.seed - cte1.seed difference
from cte1, 
     cte2
where cte1.rn = cte2.rn;
```

> ```
> min(run_date) | max(run_date) | difference
> ------------: | ------------: | ---------:
>             3 |             5 |          7
>             9 |            13 |         84
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=248bde776ac3e7e317542a238e21e6da)*