# how to counting time in partition (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I looking for how to counting time by partition in condition if value=1 occurs consecutively 3 or more times count 1 activity.

Showing result on this picture
[image]

Comment: With `if value 1 => 3 times`, do you mean that there have to be 3 or more consecutive events, and that is why ID 8 and 9 is not taken into consideration?

Comment: That correct!! and ID 8 and 9 the data not important, It should be cutoff.

Comment: What is "timespending"? If the time diff betweel lowest and greatest in a frame - why 3 and 4 for activities 2 and 3 (must be 2 and 3 respectively), if records count - why 5 for activity 1 (must be 6)...

Comment: And specify MySQL version - it is critical in that task. For 8+ you can use something like [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227767/150107).

Comment: oh my bad. @Akina you right.

Comment: This is not enough to tell the misprint exists. Correct the question.

Comment: If you want to draw more attention to your question, either post `CREATE TABLE` statement together with `INSERT` statements for sample data or create a db<>fiddle or similar.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  8.0 has some "window functions" that probably make this a lot easier.

Comment: I use MYSQL2016